# how can I tell if `hg convert` is actually doing anything?

Tags: svn, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using Mercurial on Win32 (Server 03). I'd like to copy a Subversion repo on my local drive to a Mercurial repo on my local drive so that I can test the merging abilities of mercurial vs subversion.

Is `hg convert` the right command to use?

After I do this: 
`"c:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" convert c:\dev\SubversionRepo\MyRepo -r 123456 -s svn c:\devhg\MyRepo_123456`

I get a message that says:

```
8 Created MyRepo branch again as a copy from  http://.../Branches/SourceRepo. 
There was another MyRepo  branch in this same location that was deleted.
```

OK now I'm nervous. Branch in this location that was **deleted**? Nooo I don't want to be deleting branches.

And now the convert command seems stalled. There are no files being created in `c:\devhg\MyRepo_123456` beyond the basic `.hg` folder. Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you should use '--debug' switch to see what's happening.
2. you should understand that `hg convert` can spend a long time working on that first entry. The number on the line is how many more it has to do. If that number is 600, well you got a wait ahead of you.
3. each line next to the number is the comment for that commit, not any sort of status message from the `hg convert` command.
4. `hg convert` only produces the set of changes for the repository, not any actual files. So almost all of the output will be in the `.hg` folder.

Do a fresh start by removing every thing and use "hg convert" only once. This creates a mercurial repo that you can work from, make changes and then push the changes to subversion repo.

Reference:

- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion
- [See an example](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ConvertingSvnToHg)

Comment: So my whole "oh crap it's deleting stuff" moment? That was a comment in one of the checkins. Hg convert wasn't very clear that that was a checkin comment.

Comment: Also, I did do a fresh start at the beginning. Deleted the local directory c:\devhg\MyRepo_123456.

Comment: I'm gonna edit your answer a bit and add my experiences then mark it as answer.

Comment: @jcollum: It is also nice to see, how a comment innocuously introduced earlier can confuse so much later on. :)